# Need assistance with a footprint chart

Tags: charts, trading, footprint

For a project I am working on, I need to implement a linechart with barcharts on each individual node. an example of this can be seen on  exocharts.com, anyone know if there's a library I can accomplish this with?
[Footprint chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v47MP.png)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use [d3.js](https://d3js.org) for this.  It looks like [Cignals.io](https://cignals.io) uses it for their UI.